# Slide in absolute positioned Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a background div that hosts a modal div.

I have set the modal div to have the css:

```
.modal {
    opacity: 0.01;
    top: 20px;
    transition: all ease-in 200ms;
}
```

Then I created another class to add to it in order to show it

```
.modal-open {
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

However, when the open class is added to the div, chrome shows the properties being striked out (a.k.a not taking effect or overridden).

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/no1melman/pen/zdvpOP) for demonstration. You can click on the background to hide the modal again.

Why isn't it transitioning properly?

Comment: Try this
 '.modal-open {
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}'
??

Comment: Add .modal-open{} css after  .modal{} class and it's work.. no need to add !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you placed .model-open **before** .modal in the CSS.

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0.01;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.modal-open {
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvdZMa

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that to animate it, the modal can't be a child of the background!

Comment: Because CSS working on cascading inheritance, you have 2 classes with equal weight being applied, so the rules that come after takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.modal.modal-open {
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

to override `.modal{}`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `!important` to the `.modal-open`

```
.modal-open {
    top: 50px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

or make it like this to override `.modal`

```
.modal.modal-open {
    top: 50px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```